# Ajax search for multiple parameters usng a single input box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Trying to implement a search similar to [here](http://www.proptiger.com/).This searches properties based on **city,locality,property name and builder name**.Now have a smaller version working which searches on only the locality name to which I append the city name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //alert("Entered");
        $("#searchId").keyup(function() 
        {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;

        if((searchbox=='') || (searchbox=='e.g') )
        {
            //$('#display').css('display') == 'none';
            $('#display').hide();
        }
        else
        {   

            if("#searchId".length>3)
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#display").html(html).show();    

                $(".name").click(function(){
                                    //  alert($(this).text());
                                            $("input#searchId").val($(this).text());
                                            $('#display').hide();
                                }); 
             }          
            });

        }
        }return false;    

        });                 

        });
```

In search.php I have the query like this,

```
$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from locality as loc inner join cities as cit on loc.city_id=cit.city_id where locality_name like '%$q%' or city_name like '%$q%' order by locality_id LIMIT 5");
```

But I want it to function similar to the link given.The **drop down should show the name of the criteria selected and its type in front** (Ex:Pune(criteria)           city(type)).How can I write a **sql statement and ajax/jquery** function to achive this??

**EDIT:**
Adding the HTML for the input box

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="homeinput ac_input" title="Search" id="searchId" name="SearchValue" value="e.g lodha new cuffe parade, thane mumbai" onFocus="if(this.value=='e.g lodha new cuffe parade, thane mumbai') this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='e.g lodha new cuffe parade, thane mumbai';">
```

Thanks for the time.

Comment: So whats the problem? The SQL or the jQuery?

Comment: @charlietfl Added the html for the input box.Thanks

Comment: @ZeeTee I would need tweeks to both if needed,not sure how to go about it.Thanks for having a look though.

Comment: one input for html onlY?  where is user entering other fields? If you had a complete form you can submit that easily via ajax using `serialize()` to collect all the form data

Comment: Its a search box,a single search box no multiple input fields.I am calling the above jquery function on keyup event as the user types in the values in the input box.The link i have added might help to understand me better!!Please have a look if possible here it is http://www.proptiger.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you even look at the code below, a few things to note:

- This looks horribly subject to SQL injection. Without being able to see your PHP code and what you to do $q before inserting into this query...all I have to say is: be careful. If you're not validating the input of $q, all I would have to do is type: "'; DROP TABLE localities;" **note this technically wouldn't work because mysql_query only supports single commands, but the risk is still there**
- This query type will not allow you to use indexes and is likely to perform very slow. Consider removing the % before the $q, to allow MySQL to use indexes, or switch to a full-text engine with partial word indexing capabilities. If this table gets large enough this could become quite slow

However, this is the correct way:

```
(
    SELECT
      'Locality' AS `type`,
       `locality_name` AS `name`
    FROM
       `locality`
    WHERE
       `locality_name` LIKE '%$q%'
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
       'City' AS `type`,
       `city_name` AS `name`
    FROM
       `cities`
    WHERE
       `city_name` LIKE '%$q%'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the threat out.Can you throw some light on it as i am a newbie learning these things.I will try it out and accept the answer.Already upvoted. :)

Comment: @sachintaware Sure, the threat is basically that, without validating input to a query with some function (say, [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)), you allow a malicious user to change your query to whatever they might want it to be.

For example, if I had "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = $input", where $input came from a form field, a malicious user on my site could input the string "1 OR 1 = 1" which would make my query "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 1 OR 1 = 1" which of course would return all rows of data.

Comment: Got it!!Thank you for the inputs and keep up the good work.Cheers!

Comment: I tried with this but I am not able to achieve the expected result.I want to display the locality also when a city is searched.For ex. if I search for Pune, the result should be **Pune- city** and localities of pune below it like this **wakad  locality** **wagholi locality**.I tried using a join over it but did not work as it brings some weird results.

Comment: This is the query I tried `(
SELECT * , 'Locality' AS 'type', locality_name AS name
FROM locality
INNER JOIN cities ON locality.city_id = cities.city_id
WHERE locality_name LIKE 'Pune'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT * , 'City' AS 'type', city_name AS name
FROM cities
INNER JOIN locality ON locality.city_id = cities.city_id
WHERE city_name LIKE 'Pune'
)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are best to have two different MySQL searches. Like...

```
$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from locality as loc inner join cities as cit on loc.city_id=cit.city_id where locality_name like '%$q%' order by locality_id LIMIT 5");
```

then the second...

```
$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from locality as loc inner join cities as cit on loc.city_id=cit.city_id where city_name like '%$q%' order by locality_id LIMIT 5");
```

Then use your php to concate the results from both queries with the [type] at the end of each line. Your jQuery would not really need to change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am achieving something similar currently.I think,if you have a look at the link mentioned it would be more clear.It allows to search on multiple fields using comma separated values.also at the same time it gets the type to which they belong in the drop down.Sorry if I am not clear enough.Here is the link again http://www.proptiger.com